# Biblatex multiple authors name and initials wrong order

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm using biblatex for my report and I've run into a small problem. When I have multiple authors in my .bib file my bibliography displays the initials of the authors (after the first) in the wrong order and I get an unwanted 'and'. So what I get:

```
1. Klinkrad, H. and J. Doe, 2006. Space Debris: Models and Risk Analysis. Berlin: Springer.
```

What I want is:

```
1. Klinkrad, H., Doe, J. 2006. Space Debris: Models and Risk Analysis. Berlin: Springer.
```

I've included a MWE and my sources.bib code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear,sorting=none,backend=biber,natbib,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\NewBibliographyString{available}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{available = {available at},}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {[Accessed},}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\textless\url{#1}\textgreater}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\space\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1]}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And my sources.bib code:

```
@Book{space_debris_klinkrad,
  Title                    = {Space Debris: Models and Risk Analysis},
  Author                   = {Klinkrad, H. and Doe, J.},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Address                  = {Berlin},
  Year                     = {2006},
}
```

I think it is a simple change in the definition of the Author field. However, I've not been able to find the solution anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Do `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` and `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}` help?

Comment: yeah it seems to work, also with in-text citing. So thank you!

Comment: I noticed that when I cite in text there is no 'and' between authors of the same work. I posted a question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/biblatex-in-text-citing-missing-and-between-authors) but maybe it is better to ask it as a follow-up of my previous question and your answer...

Comment: By removing \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim} the 'and' appears both in text and in the bibliography. This is what I was after, but I did not specify my question correctly in the first place.