# Biblatex in-text citing, missing 'and' between authors

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using biblatex for my report and I've run into a small problem. When I have multiple authors in my .bib file and I want to cite them in text, I do not get an 'and' between the authors:

```
 (Klinkrad, Doe, 2006) using \parencite
 Klinkrad, Doe (2006) using \citet
```

What I want is the following

```
 (Klinkrad and Doe, 2006) using \parencite
 Klinkrad and Doe (2006) using \citet
```

The following is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear,sorting=none,backend=biber,natbib,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\NewBibliographyString{available}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{available = {available at},}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {[Accessed},}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\textless\url{#1}\textgreater}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\space\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1]}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
 \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\parencite{space_debris_klinkrad} and 
\citet{space_debris_klinkrad} both do not display \textbf{and} between authors.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And my sources.bib looks like:

```
@Book{space_debris_klinkrad,
  Title                    = {Space Debris: Models and Risk Analysis},
  Author                   = {Klinkrad, H. and Doe, J.},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Address                  = {Berlin},
  Year                     = {2006},

}
```

Does somebody have a solution to this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have turned the `and` into a comma via

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
```

Removing this command restores the `and`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=none,
  backend=biber,natbib,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{available}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{available = {available at},}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {[Accessed},}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\textless\url{#1}\textgreater}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\space\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1]}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
%\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
 \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\parencite{space_debris_klinkrad} and \citet{space_debris_klinkrad}
both display \textbf{and} between authors.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Problem is solved. I added this \renewcommand line as a response to a previous [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206786/biblatex-multiple-authors-name-and-initials-wrong-order). However, I did not specify my question there correctly.